# What happens when recursion is called twice in a method?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm pretty new to programming and I have now come to the concept of recursion. I have solved a few basic assignments but when I come to multible recursion I get terribly lost. I have tried to solve the following recursion several times but just cant get it right.

A recursive method is called with the arguments `"ABCD"` and `2`, i.e.  `recMethod("ABCD", 2);`.

```
public void recMethod( String str, int n ) {
  if( n >= 0 ) {
     recMethod(str, n – 1);
     System.out.print(str.charAt(n));
     recMethod(str, n – 1);
  }
}
```

Is there somebody out there who can explain what is going on? The first recursive call really confuses me.

Comment: There is no recursion in you question.

Comment: I changed the name of the method to make the example clearer but forgot to change the name within the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to understand recursion as for me is to write it on the paper line by line. What I did for your case now. [image]

Please try to do the same, and don't hesitate to ask more question, I hope it helps!

Comment: if the `if` statements gets false.. will the current method be destroyed from the memory? i still don't get how second recursive call will start executing? cause what i could get is, if the method will destroyed from the memory then `if` block will go for the rest of the statements(second Recursive call)..correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing to know about recursion is that it's **nothing special**. As with everything in a method it needs to finish a statement before the next statement can be executed:

```
public void someMethod() {
  someOtherMethod();
  someLastMethod();
}
```

Looking at my example it's obvious that `someLastMethod` will be called after `someOtherMethod` has finished. It really doesn't matter if you replace `someOtherMethod` with something recursive. It needs to finish before `someLastMethod` can be called. When looking at your recursive method again:

```
public void recMethod( String str, int n ) {
    if( n >= 0 ) {
        recMethod( str, n – 1 );
        System.out.print( str.charAt( n ) );
        recMethod( str, n – 1 );
    } else { // base case added for clarity
        return;
    }
}
```

For each call where `n >= 0`, before the `System.out.print` method is called the call to `recMethod` has to be called. Every call to recMethod has it's own `n` and `str` so they can be considered different methods entirely except their code is 'very similar'.

Every call will either match base case or need the result of the same method with n decremented so I like to start from the base case and work myself backwards, which is when n is `-1`. Imagine you call `recMethod("ABCD",-1)` what would happen? Well it prints nothing or "".

I then look at `recMethod("ABCD",0)` and it calls the base case, which we know does nothing, then prints "A" and then it calls the same as the first statement which again does nothing. Thus it prints "A"

If we look at `recMethod("ABCD",1)`. We know it calls `recMethod("ABCD",0)` which prints "A", then it prints "B", then call `recMethod("ABCD",0)` which prints "A". Thus it prints "ABA"

If we look at `recMethod("ABCD",2)`. We know it calls `recMethod("ABCD",1)` which prints "ABA", then it prints "C", then call `recMethod("ABCD",1)` which prints "ABA". Thus it prints "ABACABA"

If we look at `recMethod("ABCD",3)`. We know it calls `recMethod("ABCD",2)` which prints "ABACABA", then it prints "D", then call `recMethod("ABCD",2)` which prints "ABACABA". Thus it prints "ABACABADABACABA"

Since `"abcd".charAt(4)` won't work it doesn't make sense to go on. Perhaps the code should have a test for this or perhaps it should be private and have a public one without `n` that guarantees `n` never goes beyond `str` bounds?

If you were to make a method that works recursively you do the same.

1. What should happen for the base case. (How should it stop)
2. What should happen if it's not the base case expressed as if the method works as intended. The catch here is that you need to make sure that each call to the same method here is a slightly simpler problem which the recursion is bound to hit a base case or else you get infinite recursion!

Thats it! It will work.

Comment: Ideally if it was an iteration solution, hitting the base case would take the flow out of the method. But in this case if it hits the base case it is moving on to the code after the recursive method instead. Right?

Comment: @underdog With a loop you could make an earlt exit ignoring you backtracking structure. In recursion you could examine the first result to determine if you want to return it or do the second. That will make it work the same way. In Scheme you could even use `call/cc` such that you could skip waiting work in the call stack when you know the final result and thus the similarities would be greater.